# AWS S3 CORS upload with predefined filename

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm pretty surprised myself that I couldn't find the answer to my problem on stackoverflow or google.

I'm using plupload, to upload images to my S3 bucket via CORS. In my Node backend I define the policy for uploading the image. Using XHR I request the base64 encoded policy from my backend.

Now the only problem that I have, is that I want to add the exact filename in the policy. As far as I know (and can find), you can only define the prefix or suffix of the filename. Of course I can define what the filename is, in the client, when I start uploading, but that wont then be controlled by the policy.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just poor reading from my side, or poor documentation, not sure :). But the 'eq' property can be used for that. So not just 'starts-width' and 'end-width'.